# Can I make several check boxes in one setting on the Preference Screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I'm going to modify the existing Preference Screen.

Can I make several check boxes in one setting on the Preference Screen?

For example
[image]

How should I approach it?

cf)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings

Comment: You would have to subclass Preference and build your own layout and logic for persisting the separate values.  IMO, this would be poor for user experience. Preferences have a precedent of being one clickable thing per row. This one would have small targets for tapping and have to ignore taps on the row that aren't close enough to one of the items.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Nevertheless, if you have to use this method, can you explain a more specific method?